# URL routing patterns for frontend pages in PHP

Tags: php, url-routing

Im creating a MySQL database driven PHP (W)CMS application which follows the MVC pattern. First take a look at the framework:
The MVC framework handles the request and decides what to load/call based on the URL, like: `http://domain.com/user/details/121` will load and instantiate a `User` controller object, and calls its `details(121)` method with the userid passed as a parameter, and then instantiate a `User_Model` and "ask" it for the detailed data of the user with the 121 userid, and at last display the result with a `View`. This is the basic concept of an MVC architecture. Nothing particular, everything is clear at this point.

Whereas this will be a CMS, I want to handle a `Page` model. A user with the nesessary permissions (mostly admin and/or root) can perform basic CRUD operations and other stuff on a page, for example:
I can create a page with the:

- tile = '*About us*' (this will be displayed as a headline of the page or the title of the browser tab like eg.: HTML title and h1 tags)
- URL denomination = '*about_us*' (this will be the URI endpoint, like: `http://domain.com/about_us`)
- reference name = '*Who we are*' (This is the text displayed in the menubar)
- page content = '*lorem ipsum...*' (The actual content of the page...by a WYSIWYG html text editor)
- and much more options like structuring the pages, to assign sub pages under a parent page, or making a page startpage (which means if I set '*About us*' as a start page, then `http://domain.com` will automaticall load that page content)...

Or I can modify these properties, even I can delete a page...etc.

---

The MVC framework makes no difference between handling a frontend and a backend call.
For example we have some requests:

- `http://domain.com/user/details/121`
- `http://domain.com/about_us`
- `http://domain.com/our_products/1255`

The first will load a backend controller as I detailed before,
but the others will load a frontend content.
When the Bootstrap loads the appropriate controller/action we look for the actual controller file, in the example above :

- `/controllers/Users.php`
- `/controllers/About_us.php`
- `/controllers/Our_products.php`

The first can be loaded because that is a 'static' controller written before, but the About_us and Our_products are not existing controllers so If it is impossible to load the controller, the bootstrap searches the database if is there a page with the same URL denimination (like: about_us, our_products). If there is, we load a common FrontEndController and display the requested page data, if there isn't, display a 404 error.

I do this because I want the bootstrap to handle all requests the same way, but I dont want to every frontend URL compulsorily contain the `FrontEndController` (e.g.:`http://domain.com/FrontEndController/our_products/1255`). So this is how I hide it from the user, so the URL can remain more user friendly. My question is: Is this a good practice? Or are there any other proper ways to do this?

Comment: OT: I hope you are using a framework to not *re-write the wheel* as they say. If so, it would helkp to know which one in order to provide help on how to configure the routing

Answer (score 1):

> The MVC framework handles the request and decides what to load/call based on the URL

What you would normally is have is some sort of `Router` and `Dispatcher` class. The router would accept the the `user/details/121`, parse it and return a `Route`.

```
$route = $router->route( $request->getUri() );
```

The router could hold config values like the allowed space character in URI's, default allowed characters etc.

You can also add custom routes to the router

```
$router->addRoutes($routes);
```

The custom routes can be a simple associative array

```
$routes['requested-uri'] = 'custom-route'
```

In the example above you said when they visit the root of the website you want them to actually see the About Us page so that could be done like this:

```
$router->addRoutes([
    '' => 'about-us
]);
```

Meaning when the URI is ''(blank) then go to the 'about-us' route. It shouldn't do a redirect, just transparently load up a different route while keeping the URI in the clients web browser the same.

Routing can obviously be more complex, using route objects added to a route collection for more advanced custom routing with more control. Some frameworks use annotations and all sort of different ways to achieve flexible routing.

The dispatcher could then accept the route returned from the router and dispatch it. That means verifying if the requested route actually exists i.e does the controller file exist and the requested method in the controller exist.

```
$view = $dispatcher->dispatch($route);
```

Inside the `Dispatcher::Dispatch()` method:

```
// Check if the controller file exists.
// Instantiate the controller file, preferably using a controller factory.
// Check if the controller method exists.

// Call the controller method
call_user_func_array([$controller, $route->getMethod()], $route->getParams());

$view = $controller->getView();
$action = $route->getAction();

// Call the view method.
if( method_exists($view, $action) ) {
    $view->$action();
}

return $view;
```

I find the following a very easy to understand way of dealing with controller methods/actions. Let's say you have a login controller, the user sends a GET request to it first and a POST request to it when sending the login details in the form.

```
public function getIndex() { }

public function postIndex() {
    $username = $this->request->post('username');
    $password = $this->request->post('password');
}
```

The **get** and **post** in front of the method name is the request type, this prevents you having to do something like this

```
public function index() {

    if( $this->request->getType() === 'POST' ) {
        $username = $this->request->post('username');
        $password = $this->request->post('password');
    }
}
```

It also gives you more control over authorisation(if you do it at the routing layer) because you can easily allow a user to send a GET request to the controller but deny them access to sending a POST request.

Each controller has a one to one relationship with a view. The view get's injected into the controller on construction, preferably using a controller factory.

What would happen when you send a GET request `http://domain.com/user/details/121` is the router would break up the URI and turn it into a route targeting the `User` controller, the `getDetails()` method with the parameter `121`, the dispatcher checks if the controller and method exist, it then calls the method supplying the user ID as an argument, the controller sets the user ID in the view. Below is the `User` controller.

```
public function getDetails($userId) {
    $this->getView()->setUserId( (int)$userId );
}
```

The view then has a method called `details()`. The same name as the method called in the controller, just without the request type in front of it.

The dispatcher then calls the `details()` method of the view which then fetches the required data.

Setting the title of the page is done in the view, as it is for presentation purposes only.

**Part of the view that is related to the User controller**

```
public function details() {

    // Fetch the user by using the previously set user ID from the controller.
    // If he doesn't exist set an error template, set the response code to 404, 
    // or redirect. Do whatever you want really.

    $this->setTitle('User Details');

    // Build template objects, bind the fetched user data to main template.
}
```

How you implement the `setTitle` method and all over view related stuff is up to you.

The view sends the response back to the client, whether it is HTML content, JSON, XML, or any other content type.

For example your application lets you search for users and export them to a Microsoft Excel Workbook file(.xlsx) and prompt the user to download it.

The view would:

- Fetch the users
- Generate the file
- Set the HTTP response headers like `Content-Type`
- Send the response

Comment: "The view would: Fetch the users, Generate the file, Set the HTTP response headers like Content-Type, Send the response." I'm not of your opinion :) The view should not do that. The controller fetches the user data from a UserModel. The controller generates the file or uses a service / helper object to create the file. The content-type is set by the Response itself, evaluating the content-type of the request. The response object sends the View.

Comment: Ok, let's say you have a resource, a user, it needs to be accessible by going to users.html, users.json, users.xlsx, users.xml. If your controller generates the response it's going to have to generate the HTML, JSON, XLSX and XML responses. Since your controllers are already doing too much now they are going to become enormous. The view is where the data gets formatted and sent back to the client, it gets it's own data and generates the response accordingly. I used to do it how you do it but one I really dug deep into it I realized how wrong it actually was.